# django ORM with asyncio

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-asyncio, django-channels, aiopg

I'm looking for something that can allow the usage of the Django ORM with asyncio (with PostgreSQL).
As of now I found only [aiopg](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiopg) in the asyncio ecosystem, which allows to run raw SQL or to use SQLAlchemy only.

I then found something in the [django channels docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/databases.html#database-sync-to-async).
is this:

https://github.com/django/channels/blob/master/channels/db.py

the missing piece that I was looking for?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like that module uses threads to close old database connections. It has nothing to do with/no knowledge of asyncio.

Comment: If you write your endpoints within channels you can then `await` Django ORM operations yes.

Comment: @MatthausWoolard Andrew Godwin himself replied to me to the same question asked on the google django users group:
***
The Django ORM can't just be used with asyncio directly, sadly. The database_sync_to_async function you found there will help you call the ORM from asynchronous code, but it still runs the ORM in a synchronous thread (see https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/databases.html)

The project to make the ORM truly async is a tough one and yet to be started.
***